# How to set part of Actionbar title bold

Tags: android, android-actionbar, text-styling

i would like to have an actionbar title like "titlepart1**titleparttwo**". But as I understand it correctly through a theme you can either set the whole title on bold or not but not partly. Is there any workaround?

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#81CFEB</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need to use themes, actually.

`CharSequence` instances can have markup information. You can add Spans manually, or you can use the [`Html`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class to make it easier. For example:

```
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("titlepart1<b>titleparttwo</b>"));
```

Comment: this is Great! but why does it say method invocation may produce null pointer?

Comment: @fullMoon Probably because `getActionBar()` might return null on activities that don't have one. You can check for `if (actionBar != null) ...` if you want.

Answer (score 3):

What matiash answered is good but it is not the native method

You should try this, also this will be faster

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder("HelloWorld");
str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 5, 10,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(str);
```